Calendar.Events.import throw Bad request error for recurring events
I am using Calendar.Events.import in Google AppScript to transfer events from one calendar to another, This works mostly fine. But for recurring events I get the following error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: Bad Request

Here is a minimal example of the code:
function import_events() {
  const start = new Date();
  const end = new Date(start.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // one Year from start

  const source_calID = "c_1234@group.calendar.google.com"
  const target_calID = "c_5678@group.calendar.google.com"

  const events = Calendar.Events.list(source_calID, {
    timeMin: start.toISOString(),
    timeMax: end.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    showDeleted: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  });

  for (var event of events.items) {
    event.organizer = {
      id: "abc.def@ghi.com",
    };
    try {
      Calendar.Events.import(event, target_calID);
      console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error attempting to import event "%s": %s', event.summary, e.toString());
    }

  }
}

It is not related to this issue.
Has anybody an idea on how to solve this? Thanks for your help!

I've tried to replicate your issue however, I am unable to get the same error that you have using the minimal example code that you provided. Could you state the line where the error shows?

It is thrown at Calendar.Events.import. But only for events that happen on regular (f.e. yearly) basis

I realized it only happens for the instances of recurring events. Removing "singleEvents=True" (and orderBy: 'startTime') helped. It seems to work now.
